# Extracting the values in the element of a list in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have `n` elements in a list `A`. Each element in the list is a matrix and every element has different size (for eg. for `1st` element the size is `a1 x b1`, for second its `a2 x b2` and for `nth` element it is `an x bn`). How to extract the complete matrix of that element having the maximum matrix size.  For example `n = 4` (can be more, not known before).

```
List A (4 elements)
    n = 1, size =  10 x 2   array([[some numbers in 2D]])
    n = 2, size =  20 x 2   array([[some numbers in 2D]])
    n = 3, size =  15 x 2   array([[some numbers in 2D]])
    n = 4, size =  12 x 2   array([[some numbers in 2D]])
```

in this list I want to extract the matrix in the index, `n = 2` using `max` function

Comment: Share with us your attempt at trying to solve this problem

Comment: how do you define "maximum matrix size"?

Comment: @jpp..for example...a3 is the maximum of all so I want to extract that complete matrix i.e a3 x b3.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to get the last element of the list.

Comment: @jsmolka.. i have added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood you correctly:

```
lst = [np.zeros((10, 2)), np.zeros((20, 2)),
       np.zeros((15, 2)), np.zeros((12, 2))]
result = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.shape[0] * x.shape[1])[-1]
```

This sorts your list by the product of the matrix dimensions and returns the biggest of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy 
l=[
  [[1,2],[2,3,4]],
  [[1,3,41,1234,12],[123,1234,1234,],[1234,34,1234,13,123,123]],
  [[1,3,41,1234,12],[123,1234,1234,],[1234,34,1234]]
  ]
max_l=[]
sizen=len(l[0])
sizem=len(l[0][0])
sizex=sizen*sizem
for i in l:
  if sizex<(len(i)*len(i[0])):
    sizex=(len(i)*len(i[0]))
    max_l=i
for i in max_l:
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Assumes, as per your example, that only the row count is required.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [np.zeros((10, 2)), np.zeros((20, 2)),
       np.zeros((15, 2)), np.zeros((12, 2))]

lens = list(map(len, lst))  # [10, 20, 15, 12]
lst[lens.index(max(lens))]  # np.zeros((20, 2))
```